# ubuntu install failed on asus vivobook 14

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I face really long stack of errors when trying to install ubuntu 20.4

this was running fine 3 months ago, then it was crashed due to an update

I waited for 20.4.2 and tried to install it this week, I got the error shown in the photo.

what could possibly go wrong? is it incompetabile with the hardware or the image.

I used etecher and rufus to create the image, same error happened.

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that the source `.iso` you downloaded is complete? 

Comment: yes, I have downloaded it 2 times, to eliminate this possibility.